# How to detect when my application is closed through swipe

Tags: android, methods, swipe

I need to catch this action somehow so i can make the notification bar of the application that appears when it goes in background disappear .

I've tried with onDestroy and onStop but nothing, it doesnt go through those methods.

** question related to my problem: [Removing notification bar when the application is closed through swipe action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403461/removing-notification-bar-when-the-application-is-closed-through-swipe-action)

Comment: onPause uses to play a mediaplayer in background, so i need to keep it open.

Comment: Why can't you do both in onPause?

Comment: read this, it's related to my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403461/removing-notification-bar-when-the-application-is-closed-through-swipe-action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the onDestroy method is called when i call the

```
startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
```

more details where i needed it in the answer of  [Removing notification bar when the application is closed through swipe action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24403461/removing-notification-bar-when-the-application-is-closed-through-swipe-action)